# Removing Element from Lists of List. PYTHON

Tags: python

```
for i in file:
   file = [i.strip() for i in file]
return [file[i:i+1] for i in range(0, len(file),1)]
```

OUTPUT:

```
[['1,3,4,5,2'], ['4,2,5,3,1'], ['1,3,2,5,4'], ['1,2,4,3,5'], ['1,3,4,5,2'], ['2,1,3,5,4'], ['1,3,4,5,2'], ['3,5,2,4,1'], ['1,4,5,2,3'], ['5,1,4,3,2'], ['3,2,5,4,1'], ['3,1,2,5,4'], ['2,5,1,4,3'], ['3,2,1,4,5'], ['4,5,3,1,2'], ['1,5,4,3,2'], ['1,5,3,4,2'], ['2,1,4,3,5'], ['4,1,2,5,3']]
```

This is my List with sub-lists.

How can I take off the `' '`? So `['1,3,4,5,2'] -> [1,3,4,5,2]`

Thanks! (:

Comment: please format your code and share your efforts

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Comment: So your question is how to parse **str** to **list**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
s = [['1,3,4,5,2'], ['4,2,5,3,1'], ['1,3,2,5,4'], ['1,2,4,3,5'], ['1,3,4,5,2'], ['2,1,3,5,4'], ['1,3,4,5,2'], ['3,5,2,4,1'], ['1,4,5,2,3'], ['5,1,4,3,2'], ['3,2,5,4,1'], ['3,1,2,5,4'], ['2,5,1,4,3'], ['3,2,1,4,5'], ['4,5,3,1,2'], ['1,5,4,3,2'], ['1,5,3,4,2'], ['2,1,4,3,5'], ['4,1,2,5,3']]
final_data = [map(int, i[0].split(",")) for i in s]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 3, 4, 5, 2], [4, 2, 5, 3, 1], [1, 3, 2, 5, 4], [1, 2, 4, 3, 5], [1, 3, 4, 5, 2], [2, 1, 3, 5, 4], [1, 3, 4, 5, 2], [3, 5, 2, 4, 1], [1, 4, 5, 2, 3], [5, 1, 4, 3, 2], [3, 2, 5, 4, 1], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4], [2, 5, 1, 4, 3], [3, 2, 1, 4, 5], [4, 5, 3, 1, 2], [1, 5, 4, 3, 2], [1, 5, 3, 4, 2], [2, 1, 4, 3, 5], [4, 1, 2, 5, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import ast
l = []
s = [['1,3,4,5,2'], ['4,2,5,3,1'], ['1,3,2,5,4'], ['1,2,4,3,5'], ['1,3,4,5,2'], ['2,1,3,5,4'], ['1,3,4,5,2'], ['3,5,2,4,1'], ['1,4,5,2,3'], ['5,1,4,3,2'], ['3,2,5,4,1'], ['3,1,2,5,4'], ['2,5,1,4,3'], ['3,2,1,4,5'], ['4,5,3,1,2'], ['1,5,4,3,2'], ['1,5,3,4,2'], ['2,1,4,3,5'], ['4,1,2,5,3']]
for li in s:
   l.append(list(ast.literal_eval(li[0])))
```

**note**: **ast** is a built-in (standard) module if you don't know it, it cames with python installation

Answer (score 0):

One line solution :

```
list_1=[['1,3,4,5,2'], ['4,2,5,3,1'], ['1,3,2,5,4'], ['1,2,4,3,5'], ['1,3,4,5,2'], ['2,1,3,5,4'], ['1,3,4,5,2'], ['3,5,2,4,1'], ['1,4,5,2,3'], ['5,1,4,3,2'], ['3,2,5,4,1'], ['3,1,2,5,4'], ['2,5,1,4,3'], ['3,2,1,4,5'], ['4,5,3,1,2'], ['1,5,4,3,2'], ['1,5,3,4,2'], ['2,1,4,3,5'], ['4,1,2,5,3']]




print([[int(item_3) for item_3 in item_1 if item_3.isdigit()] for item in list_1 for item_1 in item])
```

output:

```
[[1, 3, 4, 5, 2], [4, 2, 5, 3, 1], [1, 3, 2, 5, 4], [1, 2, 4, 3, 5], [1, 3, 4, 5, 2], [2, 1, 3, 5, 4], [1, 3, 4, 5, 2], [3, 5, 2, 4, 1], [1, 4, 5, 2, 3], [5, 1, 4, 3, 2], [3, 2, 5, 4, 1], [3, 1, 2, 5, 4], [2, 5, 1, 4, 3], [3, 2, 1, 4, 5], [4, 5, 3, 1, 2], [1, 5, 4, 3, 2], [1, 5, 3, 4, 2], [2, 1, 4, 3, 5], [4, 1, 2, 5, 3]]
```

> in detailed :

```
for item in list_1:
    for item_1 in item:
        new=[]
        for item_3 in item_1:
            if item_3.isdigit():
                new.append(int(item_3))
        print(new)
```